# Meaning of 'calcination' figuratively

Tags: meaning-in-context, nouns

I'd like to know the meaning of 'calcination' here:

> Chinese civilization is one of the world’s ancient calcinations.

[From advantour.com](https://www.advantour.com/china/history.htm)

Comment: You need to provide the context where you found the phrase. Please write IN the question (NOT in a comment), the source, and what was written before and after the phrase.

Comment: The word "calcination" should either be plural (calcinations) or the sentence should be something like "China is one of the world's most ancient examples of calcination". You can't say "...one of..." and then use a singular noun. Did you copy this directly from where you found it?

Comment: BoldBen: I reworded the original, it appears I mistook the idea,,,originally it goes: https://www.advantour.com/china/history.htm

Comment: It’s a typo for *civilization*. Maybe due to autocorrect. The rest of the article makes it clear it was not written by a native speaker of English. Best to just write off these small errors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be based either on a typo or a faulty auto-correct.

Answer (score 2):

Calcination is the process which heats calcium carbonate to its decomposition into calcium oxide and carbon dioxide. The calcium oxide can then be used to make ceramics or cement.

EDIT - The OP has now added a link to the source of the sentence. As user *Dan Bron* has pointed out, this is clearly a typo for *civilization*.

Comment: MaxW, but it does not make sense in that context; China is one of the world’s ancient cancinations.